# Display different accounts in different browsers

Tags: php, web

I was wondering is it possible to use PHP to **display two browsers**, **both logins with different users**, however both of them **use the same device at the same time**.

In case no one understands my question above, I sketched a simple layout. (Don't judge my design, thanks.)

[image]

I tried using PHP Session but nope, it seems to be the opposite of what I attempt to achieve according to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and I quote here:

> ***Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.***

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pls use iframes, and point them to two different php with two different sessions as login

Comment: Hi Ken! Could you explain further?